# Localization by Time Difference of Arrival (TDOA) with Chan's Method

Tags: signal-analysis, estimation, localization

In the paper [Hyperbolic Position Location Estimation in the Multipath Propagation Environment](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-03841-9_21) ([Direct PDF link](http://www.fccdecastro.com.br/pdf/HPLEMPE.pdf)) at page 2, the Chan's method is presented. But, the presentation is made for a 3 base station system.

My question: How to use Chan's method when the system is made up of $N$ base stations with $N>3$?